# Web services not available in Eclipse WTP

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, client, eclipse-wtp

I need to develop a new web java service client.
However, the "web services" does not appear.
I expected something like this : http://gerardnico.com/wiki/ide/eclipse/eclipse_how_to_consume_a_webservice_with_wtp

Desperate, i have alse installed separately the WTP plugin.
That does not resolve the issue.  :-(

Configuration :
Windows XP
Eclipse 4.2.1 Juno (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr1)

I would be very grateful for any help.  :-)

Mario

Comment: Din't the Eclipse tutorial help?? http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.doc.user/gettingstarted/requirements.html?cp=31_0_0

Comment: Hi, I'll have a look on this doc, thanks. I've resolved the case by installing Java 6 runtime. I had Java 5.